# How to make post api in Oracle Apex 18.2?

Tags: oracle

[image: **enter image description here**]

Please can someone answer me how to make post api with Oracle Apex 18.2. I want to send json body and store it to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest APEX version you create REST services using ORDS not APEX ( https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html )

To properly get the URL structure you need to run ORDS on Tomcat or weblogic.

Other than that it's pretty much how you are doing it.

Create POST handler type PL/SQL

```
begin
  owa_util.status_line(200, '', false);
  owa_util.mime_header('application/json', true);
  htp.prn(:body_text);
end;
```

You can also reference individual items like htp.prn(:first)

curl -X POST \
  http://server:8000/ords/path/sql-test \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"first": "Hello world", "second":"Goodbye"}'

Produces:
{
    "first": "Hello world",
    "second": "Goodbye"
}